# How to match the string and click on selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I Have an two string in Auto suggestion Dropdown
Like 1. qapostgres112axdef
2. qapostgres112

I need to match the second value (qapostgres112) and need to click on it.
for that I used the contains() method.
since, both the String contains the same characters 'qapostgres112'
selenium performs click operation on first string.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@role=\"combobox\"]")).click();
    WebElement project = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"search\"]"));
    project.click();
    project.sendKeys("qapostgres112");
    
    List<WebElement> ddown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below\"]"));
    for (WebElement element : ddown) {
        
        if (element.getText().contains("qapostgres112"))
            element.click();
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both the options contain `qapostgres112`, the contains() method will select the first partial match. You can use text(), it checks the exact match.

Example:

`//tagname[text()='qapostgres112']`

Comment: Could you please check this? If not, could you provide a code snippet from the console and your script that would aid in providing some alternative methods?

Comment: I have attached my code could you check it

Comment: Instead of contains use `equals`. if statement will look like: `if (element.getText().equals("qapostgres112"))`

Comment: I have tried the using the above solution, but still its not performing the click operation.

Comment: Can you check if the provided XPath is correct? Also, check if the strings are case sensitive, if yes then equals will not work.
I see a syntax error, after if condition the curly bracket is not present, it should be:

```java
List<WebElement> ddown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below\"]"));
    for (WebElement element : ddown) {
        
        if (element.getText().equals("qapostgres112"))
        {
            element.click();
            break;
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Yes it was correct. If I print the values then its printing the listed values

Comment: After changed Xpath working fine, Thanks For Your Guidance Pooja

Answer (score 0):

You can use various methods available under the `Select` class in Selenium to select a value from a dropdown.

**selectByVisibleText(String args)**

```
Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("ANTARCTICA");
```

**selectByIndex(String args)**

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("<< id exp>>")));
s.selectByIndex(1);
```

**selectByValue(String args)**

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("<< id exp>>")));
s.selectByValue(“Testing”);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: since values are developed under  <span> tag and <li> tag. I am unable to use select class